# Groovy code cannot find Java constructor

Tags: java, groovy, interop

When I run the `main` method in the Groovy code below, I get a `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.Person(java.lang.String, com.example.Pet)`.  Why is that?  I'm using the latest version of the Groovy/Grails Tool Suite.

Groovy:

```
package com.example

import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@TypeChecked
class Test {
    static main(args) {
        Pet fido = new Pet(name: 'Fido', nickname: 'Scruffy')
        Person dave = new Person('Dave', fido)
    }
}

@TypeChecked
class Pet {
    String name
    String nickname
}
```

Java:

```
package com.example;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Pet pet;

    public Person(String name, Pet pet) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pet = pet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you compile and run in this order:

- `groovyc Pet.groovy`
- `javac Person.java`
- `groovyc Test.groovy`
- `groovy Test`

It works for me as expected if the above order is followed. In GGTS make sure you are compiling/building the project as expected to make sure dependent classes are built.

Answer (score 1):

As [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872386/339671) pointed out, it's a compilation order issue.  So I read [Mixed Java and Groovy Applications](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mixed+Java+and+Groovy+Applications) and altered my program slightly.  I created `Pet.java`:

```
public interface Pet {
    public String getName();
    public String getNickname();
}
```

Then I renamed my Groovy class `Pet` to `PetImpl` and had it extend the new `Pet` interface.  Now the Java code can compile independently of Groovy, so it does and then the Groovy code compiles and everything works.

---

EDIT: I've played with this some more, and I discovered that if I right-click my `main` method in the Groovy file and create a Run As configuration (Groovy Script) which directly references main class `com.example.Test`, I no longer experience this problem, without having to make any changes to the code I posted originally (i.e., having no Java `Pet` interface).